# Call to undefined method Spatie\Geocoder\Facades\Geocoder::getCoordinatesForAddress()

Tags: laravel

Here is my code. It gives me the

> Error : Call to undefined method Spatie\Geocoder\Facades\Geocoder::getCoordinatesForAddress()

```
public function create()
{
    $subcategories = Subcategory::orderBy('subcategory_name', 'asc')->pluck('subcategory_name', 'id');
    // $client = new Client();
    $geocoder = new Geocoder();  

    // $geocoder->setApiKey(config('geocoder.key'));

    $Address = $geocoder->getCoordinatesForAddress('Samberstraat 69, Antwerpen, Belgium');
    $lat = $Address[0]->lat;
    dd($lat);

    return view('companies.create', compact('subcategories'));
}
```

Comment: Which laravel version do you use?
Did you follow the steps in this installation page [https://github.com/spatie/geocoder#laravel-installation]?
Please ask the problem more clearly.

Answer (score 2):

If you use the facade, you simply import

```
use Spatie\Geocoder\Facades\Geocoder;
```

and you use it as:

```
Geocoder::getCoordinatesForAddress('Samberstraat 69, Antwerpen, Belgium');
```

Note that in order to use the facade, you need to properly configure the package as described in the installation procedure (https://github.com/spatie/geocoder#laravel-installation)

If you prefer to use the object, you do not import the Facade but the class:

```
use Spatie\Geocoder\Geocoder;
```

and you can instantiate the object normally:

```
$geocoder = new Geocoder();  
// $geocoder->setApiKey(config('geocoder.key'));
$address = $geocoder->getCoordinatesForAddress('Samberstraat 69, Antwerpen, Belgium');
```

Comment: i want to get a latitude and longitude from $address How do i get this Please help @gbalduzzi

Comment: i get like this $lat = $address->lat; but cant work .

Comment: `$address['lat']` and `$address['lng']`